# trigger js events like onclick from an external js file

Tags: javascript, cordova

I do sincerely apologize for this question, but this is my 72nd hour of coding in javascript and for reasons unknown to me I can't find the answer to this question.

I need to be able to trigger event handlers like onclick, from an external js file. This is how I have linked my files in my HTML.

```
<header>
<h1>McMac editing</h1>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="JQuery.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</header>
```

This is how I set up index.js.

```
var capture = document.getElementById("capture");
capture.onload = function(){console.log="load";};
```

I will be using cordova eventually, and it says there that inline JS is disabled so this is why I need to get this working and right now with my current setup "load" isn't popping up in my console.

Again, I apologize for the question but I don't know what to do.

Comment: `function(){console.log("load");};`

Comment: @FARSOS BULSARA what is element "capture" ? (form? id? or...)

Comment: in your HTML section you have no such element with "capture" id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
 <style>
     #capture{
         width: 200px;
         height: 200px;
         background-color: aqua;
     }
 </style>  
</head>

<body>
    <div id="capture"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var ele = document.getElementById("capture");
ele.onclick = function() {
    console.log("click");
}
```

Note : onload is most often used within the body element :

html code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
 <style>
 </style>  
</head>
<body id="capture" >
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js :

```
var ele = document.getElementById("capture");
ele.onload = function() {
    console.log("load");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access "capture" element that has not been loaded when you supposed to get it from dom by using this code`var capture = document.getElementById("capture");`.In right next statement you have written `capture.onload = function(){}`.That causes following console error because browser did not find any element named "capture" exist at that time so it returns null object to `capture`.

> Cannot set property 'onload' of null

You have two ways to fix it

**1.
load index.js after body element**

```
<html>
.
.
</body>
<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

**2. Wait until all body elements are loaded in dom (without using JQuery)**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) 
{
       //Your code 
       var capture = document.getElementById("capture");
       capture.onload = function()
       {
          console.log="load";
       };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it in a little different way.. Hope it helps.

INDEX.JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("Loaded");
  // var capture = document.getElementById("capture");
    $("#capture").click(function(){
        console.log("load");
        alert("Hello!");
    });
});
```

YOUR HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <h1>McMac editing</h1>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="">
          <div id="capture" style="width:100px;height:100px; background-color:#ddd;padding:2; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">
        Click Here For External JS function Trigger.
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using bower hence the path for jquery is of bower components.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would easier to get a quick solution if you show the html part where 'capture' is defined. your javascript code declaration in your index.js is correct depending on what is in your html code.

Things to consider:

1) your index.js should be in the same folder wit your html file.

2) In your index.js, you declare 'var capture = document.getElementById("capture");', therefore 'capture' should be an id of an element in your html code.

3) you use the onload event here. onload is normally used with the 'body' element to execute a script once a web page has completely loaded all content.

so if capture is not an id of your html body element, then probably that's why you are not seeing a thing in your console. please show your html code, if you need a more specific answer.

I hope this would help.